# Has the community account gone into overdrive?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

About 80% of the questions on the front page are ones that have been 'poked' by the Community account.

Is this because it's too quiet, or has it just gone mental (an early sign of the inevitable Stackocalypse)?

Comment: Can't be a sign of Stackocalypse cause everyone on holiday mood. However +1 for you - a Merry Christmas and Happy New year to all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am guessing this is because the site is relatively quiet over the "holiday" period, and nobody is voting or otherwise doing things to make questions pop up. I have hardly seen any flags over the last few days - maybe everybody is still hung over. Or maybe Community had too much to drink ;-)

Having said that, they are constantly tweaking the various algorithms in the site; from the SE podcast it sounds as though they are doing Continuous Deployment.

Let's see what happens when the world gets back to normal over the next couple of weeks.

Comment: +1 Yes, I do agree with SPDoctor.

Comment: I always thought the Community account just poked questions every so often to keep the homepage fresh.

Comment: I always realized community becomes quiet over holidays and now even on weekends.